# rm command in Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dos

I have two machines the first one is

```
Machine A : Windows 7 professional with service pack 1 and VS2012
Machine B : Windows 8.1 and VS2012
```

Now Machine A gives the following result

```
E:\>rm
rm: too few arguments
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

Whereas Machine B gives the following

```
C:\>rm
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How do I make the rm command work in Windows 8 VS2012 Command Prompt. Is their an add-on I need to install ?

Comment: I would appreciate a Reason for close ? Windows 7 does not support rm command as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install GnuWin32 CoreUtils found at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm. Then add C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin to your PATH.